# Querying Postgis data in R using dplyr package

Tags: postgis, r

Does anyone have a workflow for querying postgis data in R using the dplyr package?

R doesn't like the spatial columns in postgis data so can't read them in like a postgres table. I get the error message:

```
Warning message:
In postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :
  RS-DBI driver warning: (unrecognized PostgreSQL field type geometry (id:17846) in column 1)
```

I know there are other ways of reading in spatial data as all I want to do is join some data  that have in R to an existing postgis table using R. I'm trying to avoid exporting it to a shapefile first.

Comment: What does `dplyr` have to do with `Postgis` ? Have a look at the `rgdal` and `sp` package to load spatial objects

Comment: dplyr doesn't specifically have anything to do with postgis. It is what I wish to use to query my data. It basically just simplifies having to write SQL (something I'm not very good at) and from what I understand allows you to work directly on the database

Comment: Where is your example of using dplyr in accessing and querying Postgis connections? What is the syntax behind your error? You have to provide enough information for us to recreate your problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can load data from `postgis` with the `rgdal` package into R.

```
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

dbname = "yourdatabase"
host = "yourhost"
user = "AUser"
pass = "ThisUsersPassword"
name = "ASpatialTable" # Postgis table

dsn = paste0("PG:dbname='",dbname,"' host='",host,"' user='",user,"' password='",pass,"'")
res = readOGR(dsn,name)

plot(res)
```

Write yourself some function around it and you can use that in your `dplyr` pipes.

Comment: Hey Curlew, thanks for the response. I can load the data easily enough, but dplyr doesn't seem to like working with spatial data. I get the the following error when trying to work with it: Error in UseMethod("summarise") : 
  no applicable method for 'summarise' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial')"...

Comment: Why do you even think that dplyrs `summarise` would work on polygons? Try to convert it to a data.frame first (`as.data.frame`).

Comment: To be honest I didn't think, it was very late at night! Thanks, as.data.frame works fine.